# Can connect to remote mysql DB through mysql workbench but not through mysql2 (NodeJS)

Tags: mysql, node.js, centos7, mysql2, node-mysql2

I'm trying to connect my NodeJS application to my remote MySQL Database, but it keeps giving me a 1045 error `('ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR')`. From the same workstation, I can connect to the same database through MySQL Workbench perfectly fine.

This leads me to think that the problem was with my NodeJS setup, but copying the database to a local setup and then connecting it, worked just fine. For the sake of testing, I made a DB user with host: %, and from my Node app, I connect to the IP address where the database is hosted. I'm hosting it on my own Centos 7 droplet with my workstation IP whitelisted.

The error message I get is:

`"Access denied for user '[the test user I made]'@'[workstation ip]' (using password: YES)"`

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Check that you put in the details correct (that error is most commonly a wrong password) or start reading: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/authentication-method.html

Comment: Thanks! I tried making a new password (less complicated) and that fixed the issue. The password i had before was generated, and i copy pasted it into my code very securely. Very strange. But I'm glad it's solved.. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Glad it helped. Accept my answer for others to see in the future, if you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently (atleast I think) the password I used, had forbidden characters in it (not sure which ones). Generating a simpler password solved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

The following error:

`"Access denied for user '[the test user I made]'@'[workstation ip]' (using password: YES)"`

Usually indicates a wrong password.
Check that you wrote down the correct password and fix it if need be.

Also good to read about at this point is: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/authentication-method.html